# How are bias and variance related to overfitting and model capacity?

Tags: machine-learning, bias-variance-tradeoff, pac-learning

Many people use the MSE decomposition to illustrate bias and variance. However, is there any statistical learning theory connecting these concepts? Namely, is there a formula calculating model capacity using bias and variance?

Comment: Qualitatively, models that are richer / more complex have higher variance and lower bias.

Comment: what is model capacity

Comment: @angryavian Is there any equation depicting such kind of relationship?

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is perfectly discussed and explained by Dr. Kilian Weinberger from Cornel University.

Here are the lecture notes:
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4780/2018fa/lectures/lecturenote12.html

and
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4780/2018fa/lectures/lecturenote11.html

You can also find video recordings of the course, so you can follow up.